# Unity 3D: есть ли готовые решения или манулы по VR-приложениям для мобильных устройтв?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, vr

Хочу создать учебный проект в перспективой стартапа.

**Суть**: геймифицированное дистанционное обучение

**Технология**:

- 3D-игра от 1 лица на Unity
- VR-режим для моб. устройств (разделённый экран под линзы и использование гироскопа смартфона)
- устройство с запущенным приложением будет вставляться в очки для смартфонов

**Проблема**: тяжело наладить работу между разделённым экраном, органами управления и гироскопом

**Вопрос**: существует ли готовые пакетные решения для подобных задач? Например, ассеты, или манулы по подобным решениям